# List of all available Cocoa Touch views and controllers

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I just finished going through a few books on iOS developing and starting my first app.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a cheat sheet (or just a list) that shows the various views (e.g., table view, collection view).  I'd like something that has the view/controller and an image of what it looks like and a few examples when/how to use it.

I've done multiple Google searches and reviewed Apple's docs but can't seem to find just a list of the various ones that are available.

Comment: check out: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10

Comment: Try the iOS HIG, [UI Element Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1).

Comment: Thanks Josh, the HIG is a great doc and I had forgotten about the content views section. Although more wordy then what I was looking for this is a great doc that does show the view name, image, and which class to subclass which is exactly what I was looking for.  Now if I could find this in a nice little printable cheat sheet! haha. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a blog post with code that uses a for loop to traverse the class and print out all of its children. Shows you basically every child of the UIView class.

[List of Every UIView Subclass](http://www.themusingsofalostprogrammer.com/2010/09/list-of-every-uiview-subclass.html)

Also, here's a reference to some Apple docs:

[View Controller Basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10)

[UIView Controller class (most other views should be children of this class)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816)

Comment: This is cool, thanks.  I was actually hoping for something more along the lines of being able to look a list of various common views (like a table view, collection view, etc) so I know when creating the class h/m files which class I need to subclass.   As mentioned I'm very new and one of the challenges I'm finding is that I have created my wireframe design and have a basic idea of what I'm looking for but when I'm creating the h/m files I'm not sure which subclass I should be using (due to lack of experience).   Not sure if this makes sense. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Start Xcode, open a XIB or Storyboard, look at the bottom right where you'll find the palette.

Alternatively there's a sample project called UICatalog that shows most of the available views/controls.

Comment: I have the UICatalog and actually had forgotten about it!  Thanks I will use this as a reference for the controls as it's a very useful example of what's available.  I'm actually more interested in trying to find an easier way that I can determine which class I need to subclass when creating my h/m files for the various views throughout my app.  I'd like to be able to see an image of a tableview/webview/etc and then have the corresponding class that would need to be subclassed.